# Way to segment discriminated union into types with and without property

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Lets say I have a discriminated union like so:

```
type Route = HomeRoute | ProfileRoute | BlogRoute;


type HomeRoute = {
  route: '/home'
}

type ProfileRoute = {
  route: '/profile/:userId',
  params: {
    userId: string;
  }
}

type BlogRoute = {
  route: '/blog/:teamId',
  params: {
    teamId: string;
  }
}
```

And I have a function which operates on `Route` objects, with some optional logic if they have params:

```
function processRoute(route: Route) {
  if ('params' in route) {
    const { params } = route; // <-- this errors
  }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a way (that I can see) to check for `params` without adding an `any` annotation...

```
function paramsInRoute(route: any): route is { params: {[key: string]: string} } {
  return ('params' in route);
}

function processRoute(route: Route) {
  if ('params' in route) {
    const { params } = route; // <-- this errors
  }

  if (paramsInRoute(route)) {
    const { params } = route; // <-- this typechecks
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do the above without casting to any (in the parameter of `paramsInRoute`)?

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Route%20%3D%20HomeRoute%20%7C%20ProfileRoute%20%7C%20BlogRoute%3B%0A%0Atype%20HomeRoute%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20route%3A%20'%2Fhome'%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20ProfileRoute%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20route%3A%20'%2Fprofile%2F%3AuserId'%3B%0A%20%20params%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20userId%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20BlogRoute%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20route%3A%20'%2Fblog%2F%3AteamId'%3B%0A%20%20params%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20teamId%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20processRoute(route%3A%20Route)%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20('params'%20in%20route)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20params%20%7D%20%3D%20route%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20this%20errors%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20if%20(paramsInRoute(route))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20params%20%7D%20%3D%20route%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20this%20typechecks%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20paramsInRoute(route%3A%20any)%3A%20route%20is%20%7B%20params%3A%20%7B%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%7D%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20('params'%20in%20route)%3B%0A%7D))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I, personally, would be happy using the type guard you have:

```
function paramsInRoute(route: any): route is { params: {[key: string]: string} } {
  return ('params' in route);
}
```

since TypeScript certainly narrows a passed-in `Route` object to `ProfileRoute` | `BlogRoute`

```
if (paramsInRoute(route)) {
    const notHomeRouteAnymore: ProfileRoute | BlogRoute = route; // no error
}
```

But if you're worried about someone doing this:

```
const notRoute = "This is not a route";
if (paramsInRoute(notRoute)) { notRoute.params.oops = 'what' };
```

then you can do this:

```
function paramsInRoute(route: Route): route is Route & { params: {[key: string]: string} } {
  return ('params' in route);
}
```

which does the same narrowing but prevents the erroneous call:

```
paramsInRoute(notRoute); // error
```

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: so simple! probably should have tried that first :)

Comment: one additional thought on this, using type guards is still an assertion, so its up to the dev to make sure that the `&`-ed properties are correct here.